# adding transmit delay in COM port from tcl

Tags: serial-port, tcl

How to add transmit delay in tcl script for the COM port?

This is the command we use to open the com port how to set the delay (msec/char) ?

```
fconfigure $::gComPort -mode $::gSerialPortSpeed,n,8,1 -blocking 1 -buffering none \
        -translation binary -ttycontrol {BREAK 0} -handshake none
```

How to add delay to 1msec/char in the below marked transmit delay section from tcl ?

[image: COM PORT transmit delay is 0 msec/char]

Comment: Which field of the [DCB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winbase/ns-winbase-_dcb) does that correspond to, or are we just talking “don't write bytes so fast”?

Comment: HI Donal, currently its writing so fast i would like to delay 1msec/char. how to do it from tcl when i configure the port ?                                                             
fconfigure $::gComPort -mode $::gSerialPortSpeed,n,8,1 -blocking 1 -buffering none  -translation binary -ttycontrol {BREAK 0} -handshake none

Answer (score 0):

There is no function to designate inter-character delay when sending as specification of hardware/device driver of serial port.

It is necessary to implement it by the application itself or middleware/library that goes between the application and the device driver.

If TCL, call the [after command](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/after.htm) and 1 byte write sequentially and loop it by the length of the transmitted data.

It is like this in [this article](http://www.wellho.net/forum/The-Tcl-programming-language/Serial-Port-RS232.html), it has a delay of 10ms.

```
proc SendCmd {channel command} {
   global output debug

   set letter_delay 10   
   set commandlen [string length $command]
   for {set i 0} {$i < $commandlen} {incr i} {   
      set letter [string index $command $i]
      after $letter_delay
      puts -nonewline $channel $letter
      if {$debug(dutConfig) == 1} {puts -nonewline $output "$letter"}
   }
   after $letter_delay   
   puts -nonewline $channel "\n"
   if {$debug(dutConfig) == 1} {puts $output ""}
   after 500
   flush $channel
}
```